# How do I understand 的 in 因为广州的雨季下的那个雨真的是特别的大?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

So I am trying to understand the 的 in this sentence which came from a native speaker.

因为广州的雨季下的那个雨真的是特别的大。

1. Can any of the 的 (by itself) be eliminated without modifying the meaning of this sentence?
2. 下的那:  If only these three words were removed, will the sentence still grammatically correct and retain its original meaning?
3. 真的: If only these two words were removed, will the sentence still grammatically correct and retain its original meaning?
4. 的大:  Is the 的 necessary?

Comment: 下的那 should not be removed. Actually, you have parsed it wrongly. It should be [下的][那个]雨. 的s in the sentence put more emphasis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

因为 广州的 雨季 下的 那个 雨 真的 是 特别的 大。

1. Only the 的 of 下的 can not be removed.
2. No. Because the 个 must be with 那. You can remove 那个 ,  or replace 下的那个 with a single 的.
3. Yes. 真的 means trully.
4. No. But you should know that the 的 is belong to 特别.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the construction of this sentence can help you answer the questions.

The compact version of 雨季下的那个雨真的是特别的大 is:

雨季的雨 是 大

雨季的雨 is extended to 雨季的 **那个** 雨 then 雨季 **下** 的那个雨. The extension basically means "that".

大 is extended to **特别** 大 then 特别 **的** 大. The extension basically means "very".

是 is extended to **真的** 是. The extension basically means "truly".

You can tell that the extensions do not mean much, but the over-decorated words convey an emotion of amazement.

Comment: This person was comparing the raining between 广州 and another city.  In this case the 特别 did have some role.  Right?

Comment: @EmilyJ Yes, it can be seen as a comparison. But 特别 means "special" instead of "more ... than ...": it is comparing with everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave them all out!

But what you have is not a sentence, it is just a "because" clause.

1. 因为广州的雨季下的那个雨真的是特别的大, ....
2. 因为广州雨季下那个雨真是特别大，你需要买一双雨靴。

This reminds me of a sentence someone sent me recently, as if you were to ask:

> Where can you put 的 in 2.?

The English sentence was:

> She told him that she loved him.

Where can you put 'only' in this sentence? （Use 'only' only once.)